# ServiceFabric pass docker interactive mode argument on startup

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric

I need to know how to pass the docker interactive mode argument when starting a container hosted in ServiceFabric cluster. This how we do it in docker command line:

```
docker run -it imagename
```

How do we tell ServiceFabric to start as interactive container.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. By default, a container will be launched by a system account (likely NetworkService), without user profile, on a 'random' server inside a cluster of machines, that has no logged on users.

What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's another way to solve interaction requirements, by running a Web Server like IIS or NodeJS [inside the container](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-containers/tree/master/Windows). Then you can interact with containerized processes.

Comment: I created a console but the container is exiting after startup, even with Console.ReadLine() there, only setting interactive mode make it work as per my example in the question. I'm hosting this container in SF and its failing, if I just run an infinite loop with Thread.Sleep inside it works in SF.

Comment: This is the answer I received from SF team:https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/793